# Openni Kinect Drivers

Tags: kinect, openni, openni-kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm new to the kinect development and I was trying to install the openni_kinect stack. However when I tried to follow the instructions to install it (http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni_kinect) it seems like the branch for the drivers (https://kforge.ros.org/openni/drivers) has been closed. Is it possible to just download the openni drivers from the Openni site and link it to ros? If so how?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10219/openni-kinect-drivers/) by [SteFou](https://answers.ros.org/users/674/stefou/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2011-06-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SteFou](https://answers.ros.org/users/674/stefou/) on 2011-06-09**:
Is there anything particular I should be looking at? That is the site I have been using, and I was referring to Step 1. hg clone https://kforge.ros.org/openni/drivers and I get a server error because the branch has been closed.

**Comment by [lakshmen](https://answers.ros.org/users/584/lakshmen/) on 2011-06-09**:
following this shld help... have a look ....http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni_kinect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I just tested again on my computer and this line does work:
`hg clone https://kforge.ros.org/openni/drivers`

May be you should just try again / check your network? Can you access the url via your webbrowser, etc...

Cheers,

---

Originally posted by [Ugo](https://answers.ros.org/users/72/ugo/) with karma: 1620 on 2011-06-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lakshmen](https://answers.ros.org/users/584/lakshmen/) on 2011-06-10**:
hi... i am installing openni as well.. i got stuck step 2.. when i install, it says rosinstall: error: None what shld i do?

**Comment by [SteFou](https://answers.ros.org/users/674/stefou/) on 2011-06-09**:
I am absolutely baffled. I swear this wasn't working 2 hours ago, but it seems to be working now. Thanks!